# Bar Graph change x axis from numbers to date in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I want to ask how I could change numbers 1,2,3,4... from graph, I want dates (1 -> 11_08_2016_12_36 without .mat) in graph from variables in workspace fnames.name. I tried some function handle but it does not work. Thank you for help.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOUki.png)
[image: Graph]

[image: This names I want change to graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N={fnames.name}; %isolate the names
t=zeros(1,length(N)); %reserve space
for ct = 1:length(N) %go over the names
    temp=regexp(N{ct},'\d\d_\d\d_\d\d\d\d_\d\d_\d\d','match'); %match the relevant part
    t(ct)=datenum([temp{:}],'mm_dd_yyyy_HH_MM'); %convert to datenum
end
%plot your graph here, use t as the x-axis%
datetick('x',1) %give x-axis in date
```

Comment: This is my solution, but thanks for helping me: 
`handle = gca;
x_label = strtok({fnames.name},'.'); 
%% Remove ".mat" from text
x_label = strrep(x_label,'_','/'); 
%% Because MATLAB takes "_" as index so I changed it as "/"
set(handle,'XTick'[1:size(fnames,1)],'XTickLabel',x_label,'XTickLabelRotation',45) 
%% Choose x_label with variable size and rotate 45°`

Answer (score 0):

Use the axis handles.

```
data=rand(3,1);  

hfig = figure;
hax = axes;
hbar = bar(1:3,data);
dates={'Date 1';'Date 2';'Date 3'};
hax.XTickLabel=dates;
% In case you want your labels rotated. 
hax.XTickLabelRotation=90;
```

Comment: I want to automatically change the numbers from graph to date from workspace fname.name where i have 41 date, so each column will be the date from variables fname.name

Comment: Changes `dates=` with `fname.name=` assuming that fname.name is also a cell array. I didn't write it like that as you didn't specify whether fname.name is a cell array or string array.

Comment: I didn't notice that you screenshotted your code; is it a structure with character arrays in it? In that case you could use struct2cell() to bring it to a cell array and put it in the axis handle.

Comment: I attached picture of variables fnames.name which I want change in graph.